How to redirect Partner Community URL(Impartner) to new experience cloud site?
Our company has Partner community hosted on Impartner Platform and now we are migrating to Salesforce Experience cloud. We want to setup redirects for the links from old impartner platform so that the user will be redirected to the new page from experience cloud.
Based on this article (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_url_redirects.htm&type=5) it suggest this is possible, but when I tried it gives following error:
Error on Source URL: https://test.stage.impartner.live/testpage/. Source must be a relative url, beginning with /
I want to setup redirect as below:
from Impartner URL:  https://test.stage.impartner.live/testpage/
to SFDC URL: https://xxx--test.sandbox.my.site.com/partner/s/test-page
Below are the steps I used:
Setup -> Digital Experieces -> All Sites ->Splunk Partner -> Workspaces -> Administration -> URL redirects -> Import -> Upload attached csv. -> Error is displayed.
Also, tried with this option -> Administration -> Pages -> Go to site.com studio -> Site Configuration -> URL redirect -> Create new redirect - >Similar error.
Is it possible to redirect from external application to salesforce community pages? Please advise. Thanks

The redirect from the external app has to live on the platform that serves that app, i.e. impartner.live .
